# Android - resuming activities without killing previous activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to know how to switch between 2 activities without killing any of the 2 activities, So that I can resume it's state.
I tried this:

Activity1.class

```
    Intent i=new Intent(this,Activity2.class)
    startActivity(i);
```

Activity2.class

```
    Intent i=new Intent(this,Activity2.class)
    startActivity(i);
```

This codes just creates another activity and destroys the previous activity when I press back button. What I need is how can I switch activities while pausing the previous and resume to the previously paused activity without killing the activity I'm at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT), and **if** you already have an instance of the activity it will bring it to front and call its `onResume()`.
The **if** is because Android can kill your background activity any time if the system lack of resources.

```
Intent i=new Intent(this,Activity2.class)
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(i);
```

Also check [FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP), depends on your app logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set flag on Intent (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK).
But you have to remember that system may kill your activity when he needs memory.

Comment: I tried what you said just now. I flag the intent on both activities, but whenever I start the activity with that intent, it just creates a new activity and does not resume it

Comment: It is impossible what you said. Let's see source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Comment: What I understand about using `startActivity()` is that by just calling that method creates a new task of activity. I tried searching for a flag to resume an activity but found nothing to solve my problem